# How select nested dictionary convert to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api

I want to transforms data on api call to dataframe but data have nested dictionary.Please let me know how to do.

```
coins =exchange.fetch_ticker(symbols)
coins
```

result

```
{'symbol': 'ETH/USD',
 'timestamp': 1612383081190,
 'datetime': '2021-02-03T20:11:21.190Z',
 'high': None,
 'low': None,
 'bid': 1623.0,
 'bidVolume': None,
 'ask': 1623.8,
 'askVolume': None,
 'vwap': None,
 'open': None,
 'close': 1624.5,
 'last': 1624.5,
 'previousClose': None,
 'change': None,
 'percentage': 0.05971415519154213,
 'average': None,
 'baseVolume': None,
 'quoteVolume': 77553533.3733,
 'info': {'ask': 1623.8,
  'baseCurrency': 'ETH',
  'bid': 1623.0,
  'change1h': -0.01186636645773748,
  'change24h': 0.05971415519154213,
  'changeBod': 0.07082563967290953,
  'enabled': True,
  'highLeverageFeeExempt': True,
  'last': 1624.5,
  'minProvideSize': 0.001,
  'name': 'ETH/USD',
  'postOnly': False,
  'price': 1623.8,
  'priceIncrement': 0.1,
  'quoteCurrency': 'USD',
  'quoteVolume24h': 77553533.3733,
  'restricted': False,
  'sizeIncrement': 0.001,
  'type': 'spot',
  'underlying': None,
  'volumeUsd24h': 77553533.3733}}
```

i try to following code but Error

```
df=pd.DataFrame(coins['info'],index='baseCurrency')
```

TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'baseCurrency' was passed

And if i want get details first data or selected dict to dataframe exclude coins[info]. How to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check `pandas` documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to understand how to initialize a `DataFrame` using a dictionary.

The two following lines will work for you

```py
# creates an empty DataFrame where the columns are coins['info'] keys
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=coins['info'].keys())

# appends a single record to the DataFrame
df.append(coins['info'], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just put `[]` around `baseCurrency`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(coins['info'],index=['baseCurrency'])
```